# iframe not loading at all on events posts

Tags: iframe

My iframe from Resident Advisor won't load. It hadn't had issues previously loading and Soundcloud embeds still work.

The iframe is located just above the image 
http://bunker-music.com/event/snts-august-2018/

```
<iframe src="https://www.residentadvisor.net/widget/event/1129341/tickets" height="400" width="500" frameborder="0" /> </iframe>
```

I've tried Resident Advisor support, updating/uninstalling plugins & no luck. The iframe works just fine when I tried placing on a different site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iframe is throwing a Content Security Policy header error related to frame ancestors. It seems to me like the owner of the iframe is enforcing it not to show on non-https environments. For more info on the CSP frame ancestor setup, you can read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors